# please help me in solving following exception?

Tags: android

On a button click i want to show contact list & retrieve the contact number selected by user .
here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int level;
    final int PICK_CONTACT =1;
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setWidth(100);
        textView.setHeight(100);


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
           //Contracts class is deprecated , please tell any other alternative if possible.
        Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

      switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
//here am retrieving name , please tell how to retrieve number as well             
 String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
              textView.setText(name);
              // TODO Fetch other Contact details as you want to use

            }
          }
          break;
      }
    }


}
```

added permission in manifest file :android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

don't know is it actually required  or not.

Please also tell if i ant to retrieve multiple contacts selected by user from contact list.

here is my log:

```
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    ... 11 more
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://contacts, calling user: android.uid.system:1000, calling package is one of: [com.sec.android.app.popupuireceiver, com.android.Preconfig, com.sec.app.RilErrorNotifier, com.sec.android.providers.drm, com.android.server.vpn, com.android.systemui, com.android.providers.security, com.wssyncmldm, com.android.settings, com.wssnps, com.android.bluetoothtest, com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp, com.sec.android.app.factorytest, com.android.settings.mt, com.samsung.InputEventApp, com.sec.dsm.system, com.sec.android.app.wlantest, com.samsung.AlertRecipients, com.sec.android.app.personalization, android, com.sec.android.app.selftestmode, com.google.android.backup, com.android.providers.settings, com.android.providers.subscribedfeeds, com.sec.android.app.lcdtest]
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getProviderMimeType(ActivityManagerNative.java:2846)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.content.ContentResolver.getType(ContentResolver.java:215)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.content.Intent.resolveType(Intent.java:3268)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at android.content.Intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(Intent.java:3290)
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at 
11-17 15:28:58.265: E/AndroidRuntime(12359):    at com.example.sms.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)
```

Comment: Is your method listed in your Android Manifest? Each activity must have a listing or it will fail.

Comment: What is at line 82 in MainActivity?

Comment: Hi, 

most likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901187/android-2-1-how-to-get-phone-numbers-of-contacts

Comment: you have try `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` instead of `Contacts.CONTENT_URI`

Comment: activity is listed in manifest file & method(onclick) to be called on click of button defined in layout property android:onclick = "onClick"

Answer (score 0):

in your button onclick you have to add intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); this is missing on your code please use the following code.

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 intent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```