# Synchronizing the app logo in contacts info in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I am working on a demo project in which On opening the general (system default) contacts list in mobile phone, my application users should have the app logo in their contacts info and when on clicking them, it should directly connect to the application (Just like whatsapp). The App logo should be directly added to the user's contact info screen and application firing should be done through on click of that logo. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this a repeat of other stack overflow questions but try these outcomes, also some of your current code would help people a bit more.

[Integrate my app with Contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact)

[Android get all contacts telephone number in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243278/android-get-all-contacts-telephone-number-in-arraylist)

[Android 2.1 How to get Phone Numbers of contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901187/android-2-1-how-to-get-phone-numbers-of-contacts)

[Read all contact's phone numbers in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android)

https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/

I'd have a look on the stack overflow forums and just around different sites before you post a question! But there you go, have a look at those various links.

Comment: Ok. But I have all the contacts loaded in my application. What I need is, my app logo should appear in the contact list of phone. If 10 persons are using my app, then that 10 persons contact info should contain my app logo. On clicking that logo, it should direct to the application

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, I'd edit it before someone else does to make it how you want it to be perceived. 
So you just want to draw your icon/logo at each contacts name/number?

Comment: Not exactly, my app users should have the app logo added in their contact info. By clicking that app logo, it should directly open my application's chat screen.

Comment: This question is similar and worded a bit better:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479352/integrate-my-app-with-contact

Also-its got an answer! :)

Comment: No. Its entirely different from my question. Ok. I will try to give you a clear picture. For example, My app name is X. I am opening my general (system default) contact list in phone. The persons who are all registered users of my app X, will have my app logo in their contact info. So that I can easily identify, who are all using my app X from the general contact list itself. And too I can start chatting with them, on clicking the app X logo from their contact info. This will directly open the chat screen with them in my application. That's it.

Comment: Yeh, thats similar with that question, you want to integrate your app with the contact list in the phone (system default)... 
The code will most likely be very similar as you just want your icon and an activity trigger that takes the user to your own app.

Comment: That is adding the application short cut in pop up window, but I need make the above changes in the phone contact itself.

Comment: @Surendar if you want to clarify your question, then comments on an answer are not the place to do it. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31402226/edit) your question to include additional information instead. Thank you.